Point in polygon problem: Ray casting algorithm or Winding number algorithm
I'm developing a video game and I need to know if a point is inside a polygon. I have read a Wikipedia article about Point in Polygon problem, but they don't mention if the set of vertices has to be ordered in some way, probably a vertex followed by an adjacent vertex.
Do I need to order the polygon's vertices in some way?
